# Rolling and passing dice in Inn-Fighting

Tags: inn-fighting

We picked up the d&d dice game Inn-Fighting by Wizards of the Coast yesterday and gave it a whirl.

A few questions came up that the rules and available FAQs don't seem to clarify.

1. I have a wizard adventurer, who has a defense ability that has me roll all 6 dice and deal damage other characters. If Bob attacks me and I sucessfully use this ability and roll all 6 dice, what will get passed to the next player - whatever my ability's roll came up, or should I reset the dice back to what Bob rolled before his attack?
2. On a similar note, what if the defense die shows an ale or dice, and someone needs to roll it. Do they reset it back to what it showed before they rolled, or pass it as whatever it just came up as?

We ended up ruling whatever any dice last rolled gets passed, but I'd love to have a clarification on that.